# SparkR fails writing Dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I try to execute a Job that reads a text file from HDFS and counts the number of words in each sentence in SparkR. It runs perfectly fine on small amounts of data, but fails when I increase the data size to roughly 1GB.

```
input <- read.text(inFile)

count <- function(text) {
    value <- apply(text, 1, function(line) {
      splits <- strsplit(line, "\\W+")[[1]]
      t <- length(splits)
      return(as.character(t))
    })
    return(data.frame(value, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
}

count_schema <- structType(structField("value", "string"))

splitText <- dapply(input, count, count_schema)

write.df(splitText, outFile, source="csv", mode = "overwrite")
```

The job fails after ~ 1 hour with following error message:

`17/04/19 17:58:39 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.`

followed by

```
17/04/19 17:58:39 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd(0,1492617519955)
17/04/19 17:58:39 ERROR RBackendHandler: csv on 12 failed
```

I tried plain *text*, *csv*, and *parquet* as output formats, all failing with the same error.

Do I specify the wrong output or is something wrong with my dapply UDF?

Comment: R UDFs are very expensive. Why not something like `length(expr("split(value, '\\\\W+')"))`?

Comment: Could you give me a more detailed example, how I would use this?

Comment: Just take the expression shown above and use it with `select`. You may have to adjust it a bit to handle empty strings with the same semantics.